# Has any other browser apart from Chrome implemented WebRTC as of now?

Tags: browser, webrtc

Google has taken up the implementation of WebRTC in Chrome very seriously as indicated by the frequent updates in the Canary and Beta channel of Chrome. Are there any other browsers who are upto implementing this?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/webrtc4ie/ - webrtc4ie is a WebRTC extension for Microsoft Internet Explorer 9 and later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Opera Mobile](http://weblog.bocoup.com/javascript-webrtc-opera-mobile-12/) does offer support to WebRTC. And according to [this](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/04/webrtc-efforts-underway-at-mozilla/) article, Mozilla isn't all that far behind either. Ericsson Labs has their own [custom browser](https://labs.ericsson.com/apis/web-real-time-communication/downloads) which supports WebRTC. But it runs only on Ubuntu as of now. WebRTC itself is still under development and I'm sure that we can see complete support from all major browsers in some time.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox/IE/Opera are working on it. No word from Apple/Safari or Microsoft/IE, although IE is unlikely at best, because they're working on their own standard unfortunately. Crazier things have happened, but I wouldn't count on it. Apple has been fairly mum on the subject.

If you want support for those other browsers, we built a solution for it @ Frozen Mountain (I work there) using [IceLink](http://www.frozenmountain.com/downloads#icelink).

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla is far along in implementing WebRTC, and we're leading the design and implementation of DataChannels within WebRTC, as well as Identity work.  We're working on a project-specific repo right now (alder), but pieces have already moved over into mozilla-central, such as initial support for getUserMedia.